# CSS3 transform rotate a nested background image

Tags: css, background-image, css-animations

I have a background which exists of 3 images in total. However the middle background image *(wrapper2)* is visually 'between' two background images *(wrapper1 and wrapper2)*.
When I try to rotate that middle image *(wrapper2)*, the top-most image *(wrapper3)* also moves.

How can I prevent this, so that only the middle background-image *(wrapper2)* can rotate and not also the other one *(wrapper3)*?

```
<div id="wrapper1">
<div id="wrapper2">
<div id="wrapper3">
<!-- blabla -->
</div>
</div>
</div>

#wrapper1 {
        background-image: url("../media/bg1.png");
        background-size: 300px 200px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#wrapper2 {
        background-image: url("../media/bg2.png");
        background-size: 300px 200px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#wrapper3 {

        background-image: url("../media/bg3.png");
        background-size: 300px 200px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


#wrapper2:hover 
{
    animation: TestAnim;        
      animation-iteration-count:  infinite;     
    animation-duration: 10s; 
}

@keyframes TestAnim
{
 0% { transform:rotate(0deg); }
 25% { transform:rotate(-4deg); }
 100% { transform:rotate(0deg); }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, wasn't possible the way I worked.
I could either position the divs (absolute/relative) and make them siblings instead of childs.

But i've choosen to create a sprite image of all the rotations that I wanted and using an css3 animation.

In the CSS keyframes animation I move the background position every time:

```
0% { background-position: 0 0; width: 300px; height: 200px; }
1% { background-position: 0 -200px; width: 300px; height: 200px; }
...
```

Important is that you have to define the **step-start**!

```
animation-timing-function: step-start;
```

This step-start works fine in Internet Explorer 10.
**Remark:** For older browsers, the animation will not work *(CSS3 is not known or step-start is not known)* and your first sprite will be displayed, so make sure your first sprite is your initial state.

For your information: I used The GIMP to create my animation and used a plugin called CSS WebSprites to automatically generate my sprites and CSS code:
[The GIMP CSS WebSprites plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25908)